# AngularJS set parent height from ng-repeat

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat that has a variable height.
If I use a fixed height everything looks good. But I need the height of the parent panel to adjust automatically according to the ng-repeat child elements, otherwise I have overflow problems.

Is there any way to do this?

With Fixed height (see overflow at the bottom):

[image: Overflow problems]

Without Fixed Height:

[image]

The code of the panels:

```
<div class="my-panel" ng-repeat="x in month.days">
    <div class="panel-today" ng-show="x.today">
        TODAY
    </div>
    <div class="panel" ng-class="x.panel_class">
        <div class="panel-heading {{x.weekend}}">{{x.day}} {{x.date | date : 'dd-MM'}}</div>
        <div class="panel-body my-panel-body">
            <div ng-show="x.suspension != ''" style="width: 100%; text-align: center">
                <b>{{x.suspension}}</b>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="x.suspension == ''">
                <div class="well well-sm day-well">
                    <div class="day_period">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            {{x.times.day.from}}<br/>
                            {{x.times.day.to}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="day_head">DAY</div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="grade in x.staff.day.m">
                        <div  class="letterCircleM">
                            {{grade.code}}
                        </div> S SIPHO
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="grade in x.staff.day.f" class="letterCircleF">
                        {{grade.code}}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="well well-sm day-well">
                    <div class="day_period">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            {{x.times.night.from}}<br/>
                            {{x.times.night.to}}
                        </div>
                        <div class="day_head">NIGHT</div>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-repeat="grade in x.staff.night.m">
                        <div  class="letterCircleM">
                            {{grade.code}}
                        </div> S SIPHO
                    </div>
                        <div ng-repeat="grade in x.staff.night.f" class="letterCircleF">
                        {{grade.code}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <div class="panel-suspend" ng-show="x.suspension != ''">
                SUSPENDED
            </div>
            <div ng-show="x.suspension == ''">
                {{x.contract}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fixed height works for you, why don't you add it to the parent based on the length of the data you are repeating in ng-repeat via ng-style?

`ng-style="{
 'height': 30 * RepeatData.length + 'px'
}`

30 is the height of one "repeated" block